# Is it possible to make a call from an Android application without notifying the user?

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which I have to make a call after a certain recurring event in background, so that the user should have no idea about the call being made. Also I have to simulate the call, that is, after a specific amount of time a digit is to be entered. How to perform this in android? Moreover, I am not doing any virus programming or stuff, I am developing an application to facilitate the user to subscribe to call packages on the start of every month without annoying him/her.

Comment: Don't do it. If your user like your service they will take 30s to make the call.

Comment: I can understand that @StephaneMathis, but this application does that much more than making a call every month, its just a feature. Moreover, it is specific for a single region. Infact, I am developing it for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So technically there are many ways to do what you are doing. The most common is by using a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). This is like a background process inside the JVM, however, it is always recommended to include a notification that the service is running (I don't believe this is a hard requirement) in the notification bar. I don't see why this wouldn't be ok as the user could clear the message.

However, when you do make the call (without some very theoretical native gymnastics) the user will be notified.

The other option is to create a service that consumes a PBX (or some such) to call your phone number and include the phone number as the ID. This would prevent International Charges (or a host of other reasons people wouldn't want this) and allow you to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: You might also be able to interface with the Google calendar app and do a cronish style setup. Running in the background continuously for days on end does not seem efficient.

Comment: I know I have to use a service, but is it possible to make a call in background and simulate it in android? Because I have read on some forums that it is impossible without the user notice.

Comment: What do you mean by "Call in the background and simulate" you always have to start an application to start a service. Once the service is running it can be binded to a bunch of different interfaces. So I guess without more detail I don't know you will get a good answer.

Comment: And also under normal circumstances you always have to "notify" the user (security settings on install). But as long as the app is installed and has the proper permissions it should be able to do anything.

Comment: Ofcourse an activity will have to start it. But from your answer, I have inferred that it is possible, all I have to do is to grab some knowledge about the services.

Comment: Cool hope it helps there are some examples of services in the SDK code that you DL

Comment: BTW I didn't say you had to start an "activity" I said an application. I am pretty sure you can start services without having an actual activity.

Comment: Oh wait I misunderstood what you were asking the call to the phone service is your issue. Yeah that will require a user input. Again there are possible ways around this (Create an online service to make the call) but if you use the Android Service than yes you will need permission

Comment: Actually, this is what I want. I'll feed in a number to call at, and a sequence of digits to be entered during the call. All I want is that my application makes a call, enter those digits after constant interval of time once the call has been picked. But the user should have no idea of all this procedure, he should only click the button to do this stuff.

Comment: right but why can't the call be made using an online service and just include an ID code (phone number), then you could pay the price of the call (IE why Android's Call service doesn't allow this in the first place) and still have it do exactly what you want. If you are going to try to hack making a call without permission brush up on your NDK because you are going native my friend (if you are lucky)